# Mongoid 3 gem dependency

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

I want to upgrade my mongoid gem to 3.0 so I can upgrade activeadmin-mongoid in order to get a new feature.

My mongoid-mapreduce gem however has a dependency on 2.0. Is there a way around this? Is there a way to see if mongoid-mapreduce would still work w/ mongoid 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid 3.0 is **not** backwards-compatible with version 2. Said gem won't work with mongoid v3 as it is, because of dependency specification. Even if you fork it and update dependency, it's still highly unlikely that it will work. A lot of things changed since v2. You need to fork that gem and adapt the code (or ask authors to do so).

Comment: There is a better support for Map/Reduce in Mongoid 3, give it a shot before forking the gem.